# EditorConfig section inheritance

Tags: editorconfig

Lets say I have the following EditorCofig file:

```
[*]
indent_style = space

[.cs]
indent_size = 4
```

Does this definition mean indent style spaces for C# files, or do I need to explicitly specify **indent_style = space** in **[.cs]** section as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your section header contains a typo and should be `[*.cs]` to match files with the `.cs` extension.

To answer the question, however, you do *not* need to specify rules "again" for each section. It's expected that a particular file can match multiple sections in potentially multiple `.editorconfig` files. Editors conforming to [the spec](https://editorconfig-specification.readthedocs.io/#file-processing) must merge the sections as follows:

> Files are read top to bottom and the most recent rules found take precedence. If multiple EditorConfig files have matching sections, the rules from the closer EditorConfig file are read last, so pairs in closer files take precedence.

"Precedence" applies when the same rule appears in multiple sections. You would use `indent_style = unset` if you explicitly want to clear the rule from any previously matched sections.

Answer (score 0):

`indent_style = space` would apply to all files and `indent_size = 4` would only to files with a `.cs` extension

See https://editorconfig.org/